# Django rate-limit not run

Tags: django, rate-limiting

I want to limit the number of login is 2, so I use Django rate-limit, but I can log in with 3rd account in mobile. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

views.py

```
@ratelimit(key='user_or_ip', rate='1/m', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def login(req):
    was_limited = getattr(req, 'limited', False)
    if was_limited:
        mess = "Try again"
        return HttpResponse(mess)
    if req.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(req.POST)

        if login_form.is_valid():
            email = login_form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=email,
                                password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth_login(req, user)
                if user.is_staff != 0:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return render(req, 'app/templates/pages/login.html',
                              {"result": "Account is incorrect", 'form': login_form})
    elif req.user.is_authenticated:
        if req.user.is_staff != 0:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(req, 'app/templates/pages/login.html', {'form': form})
```

settings.py

```
# RATELIMIT SETTINGS
#RATELIMIT_CACHE_PREFIX = 'rl:'
RATELIMIT_ENABLE = True
RATELIMIT_USE_CACHE = 'default'
#RATELIMIT_VIEW = None

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'ratelimit.middleware.RatelimitMiddleware'
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "log in with 3rd account in mobile"? Are you requesting the login page multiple times with your mobile and not getting rate limited? What are you expecting/getting?

Comment: Before that, there were 2 account logged in to web (browser computer), I log in with any 3rd account on my mobile to check getting rate limited. The thing I want when the number of login exceeds the limit will be a notification sent. Do you understand?